# Find and save file path in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a project with a unique identifying number with in it it has a folder and sub folder for named unchecked and checked, both these folders have pdf files in. I currently have a spread sheet which automatically checks these folders and counts the amount of  files in each, then shows a percentage of checked against unchecked.

However I would like to roll this spread sheet out to cover more than just one project, (all projects have a unique number) over multiple servers. At the moment I have been inputting the pathway to the folder manually, though I would like to know if there is a way I can automate this.

Here is what I would like the spread sheet to accomplish:-

- End user chooses which server the project folder is on (possibly by radio buttons)
- Then enters unique project number.
- Spreadsheet searches list of already searched for project numbers.
- If project number is already in list skips next step.
- Spreadsheet then searches chosen server for project folder and then within that the checked/unchecked folders.
- Then counts files in checked/unchecked folders and displays a %.
- If new project number was searched for then save in project number in list along with folder path (I thought this would speed up the process next time end user searched for same project number again)
- If can not find project number then come back with msg Check Project number and try again.

Here is the code I already have

```
Private Sub unchecked_pdf()
Worksheets("cover").Activate
Range("K5:L6").ClearContents
Range("M5").ClearContents
' Clears cell contents on open

Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = Range("U3").Value
' looks in spercific folder from cell value
path = FolderPath & "*.pdf"
' for file type this time it is pdf files, though if you change this is could be word files, or psd's
FileName = Dir(path)

Do While FileName <> ""
    count = count + 1
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

Range("M5").Value = count
' puts final count value in cell

End Sub
Private Sub checked_loading()

Range("M6").ClearContents

Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = Range("U4").Value

path = FolderPath & "*.pdf"

FileName = Dir(path)

Do While FileName <> ""
    count = count + 1
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

Range("M6").Value = count

Range("N5").Formula = "=Sum(M5,M6)"
Range("K5").Formula = "=IF(N5=0,0.00,SUM(M6/N5*1))"
' addes formula to selected cells to give percentage
End Sub
```

Any help with this would be most appreciated, also if you require any more information about what I am trying to achieve then leave a comment and I will en-devour to clarify.

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up, I will try it out, at the moment it is working fine with the formulas the way they are, though to follow best practice I shall change them. Again thank you.

--EDIT--

I tried it, it didn't work so I have swapped it back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub LocatePDF()

Dim CorePath As String
Dim CoreJobNum As String
Dim JobNum As String
Dim Location As String
Dim Folder As String
Dim OverallPath As String
Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, Count As Integer

CorePath = "C:\"
CoreJobNum = Range("Cover!AC4").Value
JobNum = Range("Cover!F3").Value
Folder = Range("Cover!U3").Value

OverallPath = CorePath + CoreJobNum + JobNum + Location

 Dim MyArray(0 To 16) As String
  MyArray(1) = "\Loading\Unchecked\"
  MyArray(2) = "\Loading\Checked\"
  MyArray(3) = "\Stability\Unchecked\"
  MyArray(4) = "\Stability\Checked\"
  MyArray(5) = "\Beams\Unchecked\"
  MyArray(6) = "\Beams\Checked\"
  MyArray(7) = "\Columns\Unchecked\"
  MyArray(8) = "\Columns\Checked\"
  MyArray(9) = "\Foundations & Substructure\Unchecked\"
  MyArray(10) = "\Foundations & Substructure\Checked\"
  MyArray(11) = "\Elevations & Walls\Unchecked\"
  MyArray(12) = "\Elevations & Walls\Checked\"
  MyArray(13) = "\Slabs\Unchecked\"
  MyArray(14) = "\Slabs\Checked\"
  MyArray(15) = "\Misc\Unchecked\"
  MyArray(16) = "\Misc\Checked\"

 For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
FolderPath = OverallPath + MyArray(i)
' looks in spercific folder
path = FolderPath & "*.pdf"
'for file type this time it is pdf files
FileName = Dir(path)
Do While FileName <> ""
' checks for filename <less than or> greater than "filename" as "" is empty does not,
' look for spercific file
Count = Count + 1
' counts amount of pdf files, add 1 to the last known number
FileName = Dir()
Loop

Cells(i, 13).Value = Count
Count = 0
```

Next

End Sub

So this doesn't completely answer my question though it does complete the majority of the requirements, currently the only things that are out standing is the following:

- Users can change the job number list depending on which server they are working with.
- Write final count to M9 rather than M1 with Cells(i, 13).Value = Count

*I have tried this:-*

```
Dim rOutput As Range
Set rOutput = Range("M9:M24")
For Each Output In rOutput
Cells(i,13).Value = Count
Next
```

Though I get the following error (also I don't think this is the correct way to do this.)

```
For Each control variable must be Variant or Object.
```

Any help would be great

## Edit

I have Changed the

```
Dim rOutput As Range
Set rOutput = Range("M9:M24")
For Each Output In rOutput
Cells(i,13).Value = Count
Next
```

For

```
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Cover")

LastRow = ws.Range("m" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Range("M" & LastRow).Value = Count
Count = 0
```

and it now works a treat (after I had hidden a value in cell M8 that is)

Answer (score 1):

This should really be one Macro. Relying on a combination of VBA and excel formulas causes more problems than using one or the other 100% (as long as you have that option).

So, for instance, this is a much is a much simpler overall structure:

```
Sub CountPDFs()

    Dim lngChecked As Long
    Dim lngUnchecked As Long
    Dim lngTotal As Long
    Dim dblPercentageChecked As Double
    Dim bPreviouslyChecked As Boolean

    '/ Check against previous paths

        If bPreviouslyChecked = False _
            Then

                '/ Define path for Checked

                CountFiles path, lngChecked, lngTotal

                '/ Define path for unchecked

                CountFiles path, lngUnchecked, lngTotal

                dblPercentageChecked = lngChecked / lngTotal

                '/ Put percentage in cells
        End If

End Sub

Private Sub CountFiles(ByVal strFilePath As String, ByRef lngCounter As Long, ByRef lngTotalCounter As Long)

    Dim strFileName As String

        strFileName = Dir(strFilePath)
        Do Until strFileName = ""
            lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            lngTotalCounter = lngTotalCounter + 1
            strFileName = Dir()
        Loop
End Sub
```